# How to use jQuery UI Widgets with Meteor.js?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to use jQuery UI widgets to integrate with the Meteor app. I installed the [meteor-jQueryi-ui](https://github.com/TimHeckel/meteor-jquery-ui) package. In this case, I'm trying to use the Accordion Widget. I'm not sure why the Accordion Widget is not taking effect, could you please advise me on why it's not working. Below is my code. Thank you

### JS File

```
Images = new Meteor.Collection('images');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  $("#accordion").accordion({ heightStyle: "content" }); 
  Template.element_menu.scenes = function () {
    return Images.find({type: 'scene'});
  };

  Template.element_menu.characters = function () {
    return Images.find({type: 'character'});
  };  
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {

    if(Images.find().count() == 0){
      Images.insert({type: 'scene', src:'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/f/b/8/1197091304272882353carlitos_Cartoon_Landscape.svg.hi.png'});
      Images.insert({type: 'scene', src:'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/x/p/O/y/C/9/farm-fence-hi.png'});
      Images.insert({type: 'scene', src:'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/a/d/2/12988691081493617768race%20track.svg.hi.png'});
      Images.insert({type: 'character', src:'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/8/6/e/a/1237914684389011788StudioFibonacci_Cartoon_bunny.svg.hi.png'});
      Images.insert({type: 'character', src:'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/c/a/b/4/11954237081096120744Machovka_panda.svg.hi.png'});
      Images.insert({type: 'character', src:'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/2/7/a/d/12262023651915431669rg1024_Metalic_Bear.svg.hi.png'});
    }


  });
}
```

### HTML

```
    <head>
  <title>Story Teller</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
    {{> element_menu}}
        <div class="page_related_container">
            <div id="page_editor">
                <div id="scene_container"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="page_navigation">Page Navigation</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="element_menu">
    <div class="element_menu">
        <div id="accordion">
          <h3>Scene</h3>
          <div id="scene_list">
            {{#each scenes}}
            <div><img width="42" src="{{src}}"/></div>
            {{/each}}
          </div>
          <h3>Characters</h3>
          <div id="character_list">
            {{#each characters}}
            <div><img width="42" src="{{src}}"></div>
            {{/each}}
          </div>
          <h3>Objects</h3>
          <div id="object_list"></div>
          <h3>Text</h3>
          <div id="text_list"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out. In order for jQuery UI to be applied you have to wait that particular section is rendered. In this case I just wait until my entire main template is loaded then apply the widgets.

```
  Template.main.rendered = function (){
    $("#accordion").accordion({
      heightStyle: "content"
    });
  };
```